# Почему не отображаются маркера google map?

Tags: android, android-fragment, google-maps-api-2

Написал не большую программу, которая получает каждые 5 сек координаты расположения автобусов и отображает их на карте (примерно 210 маркеров). При запуске приложения корректно отображает маркера. Но если выйти из приложения а затем запустить ранее запущенные приложения маркера не отображаются. С чем может быть это связано ?

```
package com.example.comand.metro.fragment.v4Fragment;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.comand.metro.Bakubus.data.itemBus;
import com.example.comand.metro.R;
import com.example.comand.metro.data.JsonParser;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

/**
 * Created by Comand on 09.09.17.
 */

public class testFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap mMap;
    private static ArrayList<itemBus> bakuBusList;
    private Map<String, Integer> resource = new HashMap<>();
    private static String num = "ümumi siyahısı";
    Handler mHandler;
    final static long REFRESH = 10 * 500;
    final static int SUBJECT = 0;
    MarkerOptions marker;
    public boolean BBKey = true;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        bakuBusList = new ArrayList<>();
        final ParseTask parseTask = new ParseTask();
        parseTask.execute();

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
        resource.put("0",R.drawable.bbusn1);
        resource.put("1",R.drawable.bbusn1);
        resource.put("2",R.drawable.bbusn2);
        resource.put("3",R.drawable.bbusn3);
        resource.put("5",R.drawable.bbusn5);
        resource.put("6",R.drawable.bbusn6);
        resource.put("8",R.drawable.bbusn8);
        resource.put("13",R.drawable.bbusn13);
        resource.put("14",R.drawable.bbusn14);
        resource.put("21",R.drawable.bbusn21);
        resource.put("125",R.drawable.bbusn125);
        resource.put("H1",R.drawable.bbusnh1);

        FloatingActionButton mFab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.mapFAB);

        mFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final String[] mBusList = { "ümumi siyahısı","1","2", "3", "5", "6", "8", "13", "14", "21", "125" ,"H1" };

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                builder.setTitle("Marşrut №");

                builder.setItems(mBusList, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        num = mBusList[item];
                        MarkerUpdate(bakuBusList);

                    }
                });
                builder.setCancelable(false);

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();

                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(),"cancel parsetask  " + bakuBusList.size(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapSupport);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng baku = new LatLng(40.377934, 49.891136);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(baku, 10));

        mHandler = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                if (msg.what == SUBJECT) {
                    MarkerUpdate(bakuBusList);

                    Log.i(TAG,"HAndler");
                    this.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(SUBJECT, REFRESH);
                }
            }
        };
    }
        /**
         * Парсим JSON
         */

        private class ParseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

            String jsonResult = "";

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // получаем данные с сервера

                try {

                    for (; true; ) {

                        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
                        jsonResult = jsonParser.getJsonConnectURL();
                        publishProgress(jsonResult);
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);

                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return jsonResult;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);

                marker = new MarkerOptions();
                int BUS_ID;
                String DISPLAY_ROUTE_CODE;
                double LATITUDE;
                double LONGITUDE;

                bakuBusList = new ArrayList<>();
                JSONObject dataJsonObject;

                try {
                    dataJsonObject = new JSONObject(values[0]);
                    JSONArray array = dataJsonObject.getJSONArray("BUS");


                    // перебираем и выводим контакты каждого кота
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject contacts = jsonObject.getJSONObject("@attributes");

                        BUS_ID = Integer.parseInt(contacts.getString("BUS_ID"));
                        DISPLAY_ROUTE_CODE = contacts.getString("DISPLAY_ROUTE_CODE");
                        LATITUDE = Double.parseDouble(contacts.getString("LATITUDE").replace(',', '.'));
                        LONGITUDE = Double.parseDouble(contacts.getString("LONGITUDE").replace(',', '.'));


                        Log.i(TAG, "\t\t" + BUS_ID + "\t" + LATITUDE + "\t" + LONGITUDE + "\t" + DISPLAY_ROUTE_CODE);

                        bakuBusList.add(new itemBus(BUS_ID, DISPLAY_ROUTE_CODE, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE));

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
//                MarkerUpdate(bakuBusList);
            }
        }

    /**
     * Marker update
     */

    protected void MarkerUpdate(ArrayList<itemBus> list) {
        if(mMap!=null) {
            mMap.clear();
        }
        marker = new MarkerOptions();

        for (itemBus x : list) {
            if (bakuBusList.size() > 0) {
                if (num.equals(x.getDISPLAY_ROUTE_CODE())) {
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(x.getLATITUDE(), x.getLONGITUDE());
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(x.getDISPLAY_ROUTE_CODE()));


                }
                if (num.equals("ümumi siyahısı")) {
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(x.getLATITUDE(), x.getLONGITUDE());
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(x.getDISPLAY_ROUTE_CODE()));

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ты же не кэшируешь данные, откуда при новом запуске там могут остаться твои данные?)

Comment: Разве данные не кешируются в аррейлист ?

Comment: Ну если логично судить, то при каждом запуске приложения, activity создаётся заново, и в ней создаются фрагменты, а во фрагменте ты заново каждый раз создаёшь bakuBusList = new ArrayList<>(), т.е заново инициализируешь пустой ArrayList и только после этого туда данные кидаешь.